# get css class of html text in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have a CKeditor that loads text which includes html text as well. The html text has a css class assigned to certain span text areas. When the user does a mouse-over or mouse-click on text surrounded by a span with a particular class in the CKEditor textbox, I want to fire the mouse-over event or click event.

Here is the text that I programmatically load into the CKEditor

```
var editorHtml = '<span class="noedit">no edit text</span> edit this';
```

and I am trying to catch the events via this code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.noedit').mouseover(function () {
        alert('hello');
    });

});
```

It doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here since your span is probably added dynamically by `CKEditor` here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('mouseover','.noedit', function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the this question really about? Your question reads: "get css class of html text in CKEditor". But I guess you want the `class="noedit"` element not editable. Maybe block it with a popup saying: *"No editing allowed?"*

The best way to add non editiable content is with widgets. [This post explains what widgets are](http://ckeditor.com/blog/Widget-Tutorials-and-SDK-Published). If you follow the tutorial, you will be able to create a template for a simple box with two editable fields. You want NOT editable? It's in [tutorial part one](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1):

> Please note that only elements defined in CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable can
>   be converted into editable widget elements.

By *not* specifying `editable` your widget will *not* be editable.

I do not know exactly what you try to achieve. But it seems that `<span class="noedit">no edit text</span>` should be a widget. You can still insert your widget with `var editorHtml` but you could also use a button.

I hope my answer is useful! Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using the widget earlier from a different example and while the non editable content area was indeed noneditable, I was however able to backspace and delete the entire noneditable box. This is why I want access to the class of the text. I have the code to make the entire box disabled. I just need an event to trigger it. either a click within it or when I back space into it.

Comment: Also, I need to be able to programmatically add this non editable area to the CKEditor textbox based on the html string I assign to it dynamically. There is no user intervention here. Cant find how to programmatically load widgets into CKEditor.

Comment: I think you're going in the wrong direction. You can't listen to CKEditors this way. Wouldn't it be much simpler to add the `.noedit` content _just in time_ on submit? Than you need to strip `.noedit` content and store it on load. When you want to position `.noedit` content somewhere in the middle of the user generated content you can use a placeholder. If the placeholder isn't available raise an error and let the user insert the placeholder. The big advantage of this workflow is that you don't have a listener and don't have to hack UI interactions.